# Warning: true is not a PostCSS plugin

Tags: javascript, package.json, postcss

I have an issue while building a project, this error keeps popping up:
Warning: true is not a PostCSS plugin.

This error was not visible before an upgrade was done from node v.10.x.x to v.16.14.x.
Here is the `Gruntfile.js` task:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
    cfg.postcss = {
        primary: {
            options: {
                map: {
                    inline: false,
                    annotation: 'web/webroot/_ui/responsive/theme-name/css/'
                },
                processors: [
                    require('postcss-inline-svg'),
                    require('cssnano')({ safe: true }),
                    require('autoprefixer')
                ]
            },
            files: {
                'web/webroot/_ui/responsive/theme-name/css/main.css'  : ['web/webroot/_ui/responsive/theme-name/css/main.css'],
            }
        }
```

Here is the `package.json` 's devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
  "postcss-inline-svg": "^5.0.0",
  "cssnano": "^5.1.7",
  "grunt": "^1.4.1",
  "grunt-available-tasks": "^0.6.3",
  "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
  "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
  "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
  "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^3.0.0",
  "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
  "grunt-rtlcss": "^2.0.2",
  "grunt-postcss": "^0.8.0",
  "grunt-sass": "^3.1.0",
  "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
  "postcss": "^8.4.12"
}
```

I tried reverting to an earlier version of `autoprefixer`, or moving the `postcss` to a `peerDependency`, but these possible fixes I found did not work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that one of your other packages is not compatible with PostCSS v8 - it probably requires PostCSS v7.

Comment: definitely not that, If that is the case there are warning the in the build that specify this.

Comment: Well, your warning is clearly specifying such a case - it comes from line 56 in `postcss/lib/processor.js` and clearly indicates that one of the plugins is not compatible. You can put a breakpoint there and see exactly which plugin is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to postcss-inline-svg, there are dependencies not working with node version 16.14 related to node-sass and grunt-sass. So at the moment, removing that plugin is the only solution.